# css transition jump to center

Tags: css, transition

I'm trying & learning in Chrome to move an object left to right and fading it out, but I can't figure out, why transition jumps to the center at start.

https://jsfiddle.net/kissja74/3x8tgfut/

css:

```
#splash {
position: absolute;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-name: fadeOut;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
transition:4s;
right: 100%;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
from {
left: 0;
opacity: 1;
}
to {
right: 0;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="splash">A</div>
```

Comment: You cannot animate or transition `visibility`. This might be what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/3x8tgfut/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#splash {
  position: absolute;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

[See this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jrwnb7ku/)

Like @connexo said in his comment, `visibility` can't be animated, but that wasn't the problem. Instead, you can't animate `left` and `right` like you tried to, instead you'll have to stick to one of those properties in your animation (BTW, this also applies to `top` and `bottom`).

Also, I removed the `transition` style from the `#splash { ... }` rule, it's not necessary when working with `@keyframes` and `animation` styles.